# Filter out non date values from date values in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-design, error-handling

I receive data in text format for dates, some wrong entries are also present for eg.
date 30-02-2022 which doesn't exist.
So when I try to cast text into dates, it fails with an error.
I thought of using split-part and checking maximum days but the date format is not fixed as
well, meaning some dates are like this  "YYYY-mm-dd".

Is there a way to filter out such dates and replace them with NUll?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The first thing you have to do is specify *exactly* what formats you allow. You are dealing with computers.

Comment: You could try using `sed` and regular expressions to massage your data into a format suitable for upload!